# vertically aligning a label against a textbox

Tags: asp.net, textbox, alignment, label, html

I have an asp.net webpage - In it I have an asp text-box and beside it to the right an asp label.

The font size of the label is small so the height is much smaller than the text-box.
I would like the label to be vertically aligned to the middle of the text-box.

Currently the label is aligned to the bottom of the text-box.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEveryHour" Width="30px"/>
<asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" text="Hours" />

<%--Basic - No CSS used--%>

Answer (score 2):

The best way always is to use "table"
I always do that. Helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is solving with CSS.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEveryHour" Width="30px" CssClass="textbox" /> 
<asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" text="Hours" CssClass="label" />

.textbox {border: 1px solid #828282; height: 21px; }
.label { height: 25px; line-height: 25px; }
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
.myLabelClass {
 position: relative;
 top: 5px;
}
```